# grep within nested brackets

Tags: regex, bash, grep

How do I grep strings in between nested brackets using bash? Is it possible without the use of loops? For example, if I have a string like:

> [[TargetString1:SomethingIDontWantAfterColon[[TargetString2]]]]

I wish to grep only the two target strings inside the `[[]]`:

> TargetString1
>   TargetString2

I tried the following command which cannot get TargetString2

```
grep -o -P '(?<=\[\[).*(?=\]\])'|cut -d ':' -f1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `GNU`'s grep `P` option:

```
grep -oP "(?<=\[\[)[\w\s]+"
```

The regex will match a sequence of word characters (`\w+`) when followed by two brackets (`[[`). This works for your sample string, but will not work for more complicated constructs like:

```
[[[[TargetString1]]TargetString2:SomethingIDontWantAfterColon[[TargetString3]]]]
```

where only `TargetString1` and `TargetString3` are matched.

Comment: may i ask what if my TargetString1 can be "target string", with space in between

Comment: I assumed there were no spaces in the input string. To also match "target string" use a character class: `[\w\s]+` instead of `\w+`.

Comment: this will be exactly the command i want, thank you so much!!
grep -oP "(?<=\[\[)[\w\s]+"

Comment: maybe you can add it to the answer too.

Answer (score 1):

To extract from nested `[[]]` brackets, you can use `sed`

```
#!/bin/bash

str="[[TargetString1:SomethingIDontWantAfterColon[[TargetString2]]]]"

echo $str | grep -o -P '(?<=\[\[).*(?=\]\])'|cut -d ':' -f1
echo $str | sed 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/g' #which works only if string exsit between []
```

Output:

```
TargetString1
TargetString2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep regex `grep -Eo '\[\[\w+' | sed 's/\[\[//g'` for doing this

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo "[[TargetString1:SomethingIDontWantAfterColon[[TargetString2]]]]" | grep -Eo '\[\[\w+' | sed 's/\[\[//g'
TargetString1
TargetString2
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Comment: sorry TargetString1 and TargetString2 are just my examples, there are no fix pattern in them in real case.